# Equivalent points for 3 fold and 6 fold symmetry

Tags: crystal-structure, symmetry

In a crystal Lattice how to find the equivalent points for 3 fold and 6 fold symmetry?

Comment: Can you be a bit more precise about what you want to know? My initial response would be "find the rotation axis and you'll see the equivalent atoms". If you can give us a little more on what you find confusing (e.g., how you find a rotation axis in the first place) it would really help. Thanks!

Comment: Okay..So you have to fix the Z axis and rotate and then find the equivalent points...Let's Say we have (X,Y,Z) as our initial points..so we keep the Z axis fixed and do a rotation...so this is the info..I can give u at most I mean that is what the question..I need help